# Has anyone successfully used Eclipse CDT + Eclim + CDT4 Generator?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclim

Has anyone successfully used these three together?  I used CDT4 to generate my eclipse project files.  With the GUI version, things work fairly well.  Most features work.  Although I have problems with external libraries.  For some reason eclipse won't recognize the standard library strings and some of my other external library variables.  I've read online that modifying "C/C++ Build" properties can help.  However when I use CDT4 to generate my workspace, that option disappears in the preferences menu.

Now when I try to use eclim and vim to work on my workspaces I run into more strange issues.  It seems like the completion stuff works pretty well.  And Eclipse will mark problem lines with ">>" notation.  However I've noticed that navigating the code is not working at all.  For example hierarchical call trees and jumping to the definition of a symbol.  These things work fine in the GUI.

Does anyone have any tips/tricks to help me out here?  Are there any solid guides on the web that address issues like these?

Thanks!

Comment: This question existing speaks volumes about the user friendliness of CDT. I built a hello world with Eclipse+CDT once, never repeated the experiment.